# Let's reopen this question about setting up a Mint-like menu in Ubuntu

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons, closed-questions, answered-questions

This is a question about how to get an interface in Ubuntu that resembles an interface available in Linux Mint:

- [How to install Linux mint like menu/gnomenu in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191717/how-to-install-linux-mint-like-menu-gnomenu-in-ubuntu)

This question is about Ubuntu. It mentions Linux Mint, but it is asking how to do something in Ubuntu. This is completely on-topic for our site as per [the FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq).

As [Anwar said](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191717/how-to-install-linux-mint-like-menu-gnomenu-in-ubuntu#comment238010_191717):

> I don't think, this is off-topic. The OP wants to install a menu like mate menu in Linux mint. This question is similar to the question "How to install cinnamon in Ubuntu?"

This is a perfectly on-topic question, and it has good answers too. The only explanation I can think of for why it was closed, is that the close-voters may have seen the phrase "Linux Mint" and assumed the question was not about Ubuntu, without reading further.

I believe this question was closed in error and that **we should reopen it**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191717/how-to-install-linux-mint-like-menu-gnomenu-in-ubuntu) has been reopened (see its [revision history](https://askubuntu.com/posts/191717/revisions) for details).

Thanks!